# CakePHP 3.x getting accosiated data from entity

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm starting to use CakePHP 3.x and wondering how to do such functionality in correct way?

```
$articles = $userEntity->getAccosiatedArticles()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [contain](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data) for retrieving Associated data.

```
$articles = $userEntity->find('all',[
            'contain'=>['Articles']
        ]);
```

for this you have to declare the [has_many](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)(in this case) association in User model.

```
$this->hasMany('Articles');
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use `$usersTable->loadInto($userEntity, ['Articles'])`. You can also use the lazy loader plugin: https://github.com/jeremyharris/cakephp-lazyload